# Java Parent and Child JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm new to `javax.swing.*` packages and only familiar to c#.net.
I have two JFrames namely `frmLogin` and `frmMain` respectively.
All I want to do is a simple code something like this:

+-----  C# version ---------

```
this.hide();
new frmMain().ShowDialog();
this.show();

tbPsswrd.Text = String.empty;
```

+----  JAVA version -------

```
this.setVisible(false);
new frmMain().setVisible(true);
this.setVisible(true);

tbPsswrd.Text = "";
```

+---------------------------

In Java JFrame, only `show()` and `setVisible(boolean isVisible)` is available, 
hence even though I'm not finished with `frmMain()`, it will continue to do the
rest of the code next to it (which is to show the parent form and empty the password
box).

In summary, I want an equivalent functionality of method `.showDialog();` not just `.show();`
so that it wont continue to the next codes unless I closed the child form.

Thanks in advance! Ü

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a modal `JDialog` instead of a `JFrame` and `dialog.setVisible(true)` will block until the dialog is closed. For example:

```
JDialog dialog = new JDialog(parentFrame, true); // parent, isModal
dialog.setVisible(true); // blocks until dialog is closed
// ... do stuff after dialog is closed
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had a hard time converting my JFrames to JDialogs.